# Trying to Find a Fantasy noir book from the 80/90s. detective rogue character w/ pet dragon

Tags: story-identification, novel

OK, around 1993, I pulled a book off the shelf of my grade school library and burned through it. it was about a roguish male character in a fantasy/medieval town and he might have ran a bar. He was regularly shaken down by other "MOB" like antagonists and had a parrot sized pet dragon that would perch oh his shoulder.

Answer (score 8):

I'm pretty sure your recall is a little off, if so, you may be thinking of...

The [Vlad Taltos](http://www.goodreads.com/series/40334-vlad-taltos) books by Steven Brust.

> The books recount the adventures of the wisecracking hired killer Vlad, a human on a planet mainly inhabited by the long-lived, extremely tall sorcerers known as the Dragaerans.

The first book, *Jhereg*, was published in 1987

Vlad is a member of the Dragaeran criminal organization, the Jhereg. He is also a 'witch', and his familiar, a jhereg, often rides his shoulder.

[image]